# UDP Order of operation

Tags: python, udp

Can't the server send a message first in UDP? Like the following code, the server first sent a message to the client, but it doesn't work.

[Server]

```
import socket

sock =socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('192.168.219.152',8080))


while True:
    data=input()
    sock.sendto(data.encode(),('192.168.219.152',8080))
```

Client

```
import socket

sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)


while True:
    data,addr=sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print("Client is received data : ",data.decode())
```

Comment: Edit the question to explain "doesn't work".

Comment: The client hasn't bound the socket to a port, so it can't receive anything.

Comment: And the server has bound port 8080, so any packets sent to that port will be read by that socket. Only one socket can listen on a particular port at a time.

Answer (score 0):

UDP doesn't really have the concept of clients and servers. Any process can send or receive.

But the receiver needs to bind their socket to the port that the sender sends to. So in your application, the client has to bind port 8080, not the server.

Server:

```
import socket

sock =socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    data=input()
    sock.sendto(data.encode(),('192.168.219.152',8080))
```

Client:

```
import socket

sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('192.168.219.152',8080))

while True:
    data,addr=sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print("Client is received data : ",data.decode())
```

If you want bidirectional communication, each of them needs to bind to a port, and the other one sends to that port. If they're on the same IP, they need to bind to different ports.